God/Self realisation for householders
How can a householder attain god/self realisation?
By god/self realisation I want to mean two kind of states:

Vision of a divine entity who has the powers to take my mind into spiritual planes.
State of non duality like the advaita philosophy or merging with divine.


Namaste,
As you have asked this question, I would first start from basics.
As u asked, for a grihasta,
I must suggest that, doing your daily chores with full faith is first step to it. Welcoming guests, doing pitru, devata karma, nitya naimittik karmas properly, charity, etc, all are stepping stones. As being in Grihasta and overlooking everything for sake of spirituality leads one nowhere. Moreover, read Karma yoga from Bhagwad Geeta and commentary by Bhagwadpaad Adi Shankaracharya, as u aspire for Advaita marga !
For, answering your specific questions one by one,
Vision of a divine entity who has the powers to take my mind into spiritual planes

For this, one must start with naam japa of any saguna form one relates or have faith in. There can be various alternatives mantra diksha, yoga diksha, Vedanta and lot more. Astika darshan have various paths to reach there. Thus, this is where the मल or the vices in us start to cleanse up, and we become more recipient of grace from such highly realised beings.
I quote from a book on Grihasta sadhaka Sudarshan dasa a normal man who was Krishna charananuragi and had  heard the mahima of Gurudiksha from saints in Vrindavana,

When Sudarshan dasa heard the glory of Guru diksha, he started calling to Balarama as he felt Balarama is the perfect preceptor for him. He would sob and shout, "haaa, Balarama, haa Dau", his eyes would pour rivers, he would faint crying. He started doing Govardhan parikrama, once at night suddenly he saw green grass, and cows running, and suddenly a small kid of 8 years with Peacock feathers headgear,  caught his hand and took him to his Elder brother and said, "See dau, I have brought him, he keeps yelling Balarama, Dau, like a madman and he wants to take diksha only from you. Please initiate him." Balarama initiated Sudarshan das, and he made him feed cow's milk. When Sudarshan das woke up, he felt as he had hallucinated, as all those scenarios were lost, but to his surprise the vessel of milk was in his hands and with froth of milk on it. He understood he was blessed by Balarama who accepted him as his disciple!

This was with Namajapam, there is another anecdote of Mantra japam where Durvasa mahamuni himself came to show a lady path of her Upasana, as she constantly did her mantra japa whatsoever. This is on Kamakoti site, u may refer there!
So, the crux here is to simply do as much as we can mantra/nama/yoga etc, as everyone has unique path based on past karmas, and samskaras.
To answer second question, State of non duality like the advaita philosophy or merging with divine.
This happens effortlessly once the person has reached to that state of proficiency in their nitya upasana be it namajapa, Mantra, yoga (ps-these are only 3 out of various paths open to reach the ultimate goal). For example as I recall, Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa attained ekatva with various sadhana and at the end Vedanta. Meerabai got merged with Sri Krishna Vigraha just with her Nama japa and Madhurya bhava ! Each one has it's own way.
So, find yours path, see what suits you, get initiated under a guru, and for sure you will attain the ultimate goal. Till then, Nama jaap is mandatory!
Hope this helps !
श्रीगुरुपदार्पणमस्तु
